# Synchronize audio playback with code execution (in Python)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, audio-player

I'm thinking I should be able to find the answer to this via the Google, but I've spent 30 minutes with no luck.

I need to synchronize Python code execution with audio playback on a Raspberry Pi.  Ideally, I'd embed some metadata at various points in an audio file.  I'd then initiate audio playback from Python, and when those points were reached, I'd get a chance to run some code within that Python script.

My end goal is to synchronize the audio with some lights and a fog machine, controlled by the GPIO ports.  Is there a more reliable way to do this than a series of sleep statements aligned with the audio playback?

Thanks,
-Doug